# How to get data from SharePoint list using JSOM?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-jsom

Generally we are getting data from SharePoint server object model. But i need to collect data from SharePoint List using JSOM.

My requirement is below:

There is a list called List1 with 3 columns ID, Title, Status

I need to get all those data where Status is 1 and Title = "My given title"

Please provide the solution using JSOM.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx) explains the JavaScript Object Model pretty well.

Essentially, you need to create a `ClientContext` object and use it to specify which instructions you want to execute. You'll use `ClientContext.load()` to specify which objects you want to populate with retrieved information, then use `ClientContext.executeQueryAsync()` to execute any queued instructions. Within the context of the callback functions that you provide to `executeQueryAsync` you can access the results of your query.

The below example demonstrates the typical approach.

```js
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItems,"sp.js");
function getListItems(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("List1");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml( /* build a CAML query to retrieve your items */
        "<View><Query>" +
        "<Where>" + 
            "<And>" +
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">1</Value></Eq>" +
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">My given title</Value></Eq>" + 
            "</And>"+
        "</Where>" +
        "</Query></View>");
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var itemArray = [];
        var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while(itemEnumerator.moveNext()){ 
            /* loop through all your results */
            var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
            var id = item.get_item("ID");
            var title = item.get_item("Title");
            itemArray.push(id + ": " + title);
        }
        alert("ID: Title\n"+itemArray.join("\n"));
    },function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());});
}
</script>
```